# How to catch Jquery event from vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, vue.js, vuejs2

Scenario: I have an iframe (which is hosted in the same domain, but purely use Jquery only) and it is already coded to trigger some events with parameters. And I have to catch those events with parameters in the parent vue.js application.

**iframe:**

```
$('*').mouseover(function (event) {
  var event = jQuery.Event( "mouseover-highlight" );
  event.top = $(this).offset().top;
  event.left = $(this).offset().left;
  parent.$('body').trigger(event);
});
```

**vue.js**

Catch this event somehow from the vue.js and set a div's css styles accordingly (Set the 'absolute' position). I have done it using vue.js before v2 comes by using Jquery inside the vue.js, But I've seen in the docs that vue.js isn't able to catch native events anymore. Any solution ?

Comment: You want to catch events emitted in an iframe from the page that contains the iframe?

Comment: That's right, iframe is using jquery to trigger event, the page it content the iframe (parent page) is using vue.js.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

jQuery uses it's own event system. You cannot catch events emitted from jQuery with Vue, you have to catch them with jQuery and call Vue from the handler.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    iframeSource: $("template").html()
  },
  methods:{
    onMouseover(event){
      alert(`Top: ${event.top}, Left: ${event.left}`)
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    $("body").on("mouseover-highlight", this.onMouseover)    
  },
  beforeDestroy(){
    $("body").off("mouseover-hightlight", this.onMouseover)
  }
})
```

Here is [an example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/RLwrvO?editors=1010) of it working.

Note: when adding events with something other than Vue, you *should* manage removing them yourself, especially if you are adding it in a component. Components are created/destroyed more than once and you don't want to end up with multiple handlers.

Comment: This is great, any way to pass and get parameters (for example lets say position, as in my question) ?

Comment: @stackminu Sure. It looks like you are adding them to the event, so just accept the event as a parameter. I'll update.

Comment: It worked. Please update the pen's answer on stackflow's answer and I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @stackminu They *should* be the same. Did I miss something? The complete answer won't work on SO due to cross domain issues.

Comment: Cross domain can be fixed by adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the iframe tag... :)

Answer (score 5):

https://jsfiddle.net/wx84na32/2/ Please check the fiddle this is complete example what you want.
HTML

```
<button id="testBtn">Trigger an event</button>
<div id="app">
<div v-show="this.show">
1st Argument of Custom Event <br />
"{{ one }}"
<br />
2nd Argument of Custom Event <br />
"{{ two }}"
<br />
A complete event object below <br />
{{ event }}
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript / jQuery / Vue

```
//jQuery

$('#testBtn').on("click", function(event) {
    console.log(this, 'this');
  $(this).trigger("custom", ["1st", "2nd"]);
});

//vue.js


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    mounted () {

    let _this = this;

    $(document).on("custom", function(event, one, two) {

        console.log(event, 'event');
      console.log(one, 'one');
      console.log(two, 'two');

      _this.event = event;
      _this.one = one;
      _this.two = two;

      _this.show = true;

    });
  },
  data () {
    return {
        show : false,
        event : {},
      one : '',
      two : ''
    }
  }
});
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/wx84na32/2/]

Comment: I realize this was an answer nearly 2 years ago, but it solved my problem beautifully. Thanks for this answer and JSFiddle.

Comment: I can confirm that works! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @Mihai for your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Attach event listener with Vue and emit the event with jQuery.

Comment: Just searched for a jsfiddle or a documentation on how to attach an event listener and emit the event with Jquery. Can you show me an example on this. I'm new to Vue.js. In-fact doing this on a project as an experiment. :)

Comment: with jQuery you can trigger an event like this.

`$.event.trigger({
 type: "newMessage",
 message: "Hello World!",
 time: new Date()
});`

Comment: Event listening part on the vue.js is what I don't understand. You mean is there a way in vue.js to catch events triggered externally without `v-on` ?

Comment: yes like this. you can grab custom event in vue js `this.$on('custom_event_through_from_jquery', callback);`

Comment: also like this in jquery `$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );`

Comment: @MuhammadAdil Please update your answer with the clarifications from the comments.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wx84na32/2/ Please check this fiddle this is complete example of what you want. @stackminu

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$on` to programatically listen out for an event.

```
Nova.$on('resources-loaded', () => {
    console.log('Cooking with gas');
    // Do jQuery related stuff here.
});
```

This would work on any constant variable defined for the Vue instance. Eg.
`Vue.$on` or `app.$on` etc.